# What gifts would be welcome for a Swedish host family?

Tags: usa, sweden, gifts

What are good gifts to take to Swedish family in 2014?  Many American things are now easy to find there.  The most recent postings seem to be 2012. Some say towels...terrycloth?  We'd like to get something for their little girl, too (about 2).

Answer (score 12):

Regardless of where you're going, **local specialities** are always good: the kind of thing you'd have trouble finding even elsewhere in the US.  Some ideas:

- cookies, especially the giant, (pseudo-)handmade, chewy kinds like Pepperidge Farm
- candy, eg. Reese's Pieces and other peanut-buttery things rarely seen outside the US
- liquor, eg. bourbon or Californian wine
- clothing from local sports teams, eg. sweaters or baseball caps

For the two-year-old, you could do worse than the "[Good Night X](http://goodnightourworld.com/)" series of picture books, they've got one for most American states and major cities.

Towels would be... bizarre.  They sell plenty at IKEA, and they're from the same Bangladeshi factories as yours.

(Disclaimer: I'm Finnish, not Swedish. But we're close enough.)

Comment: I really like this suggestion! My parents always were happy about historical books about the hometown or country where my friends came from. But that might be a bit too specific.

Answer (score 3):

When our friends from Sweden go home or we go there they LOVE Hersheys Syrup & Peanut Butter M&M s or Peanut M & M s

Comment: and Peanut Butter M & M's